# Rails form displays only one variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form in a rails app that has many text fields.  Upon submitting, only one field displays on my review page, however if I inspect it, I can see each field correctly. I can only see the Name field.

My controller:

```
class CrewmembersController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @crewmember = Crewmembers.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
    end

    def create
        @crewmember = Crewmembers.new(crewmember_params)

        @crewmember.save
        redirect_to @crewmember
    end

    private
        def crewmember_params
            params.require(:crewmember).permit(:name, :email)

        end
end
```

And my show.html.erb page:

```
<p>
    <strong>Name:</strong>
    <%= @crewmember.name %>
</p>

<p>
    <strong>Title:</strong>
    <%= @crewmember.title %>
</p>

<p>
    <strong>Department:</strong>
    <%= @crewmember.department %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your `create` and `crewmember_params` methods, you are creating `crewmember` record with ***only name and email fields***. That is why only the ***name*** field is displayed in `show.html.erb`. You need to change the `crewmember_params` method to below

```
def crewmember_params
  params.require(:crewmember).permit(:name, :email, :title, :department)
end
```

And also if you are not having title and department fields in the form. then you need to change it to include those.

***Additional note:***

Also I've noticed that you are using plural model name(***Crewmembers***) which is not encouraged as per the convention. Change it to singular(***Crewmember***), also don't forget to change the file name to singular as well.

Comment: In the crewmember_params, should I place every field that the form has?  I'm confused as to why email was originally listed but still did not show up.

Comment: @DanBrookwell Yes. You should place every field that the form has. And coming to that email thing, you are not outputting it, hence it didn't show up.